# ruby: Grab numbers only within quotes

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like the following sub-string

```
1100110011110000
```

from

```
foo = "bar9-9 '11001100 11110000 A'A\n"
```

I have so far used the below, which yields

```
puts foo.split(',').map!(&:strip)[0].gsub(/\D/, '')
>> 991100110011110000
```

Getting rid of the 2 leading 9's is not too difficult in this scenario, but I would like a general solution which grabs numbers only within the `' '`  single quotes

Comment: Define "quotes". Is it possible these get escaped like `'...\'...'`?

Comment: What if there are more or less than two `'`, e.g. what would `"12'34'56'78"` return and what about `"1234'5678"`?

Comment: Use the rubular regex expression tester: http://rubular.com/

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguities in my post. I know the string I have will always have 2 single quotes (') , so Im not to concerned about cases with more or less than 2. But if it has only one it would fail and "12'34'56'78" would return 34. Quotes will not be escaped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the quoted part first with `scan` and then remove non-digits:

```
> results = "bar9-9 '11001100 11110000 A'A\n".scan(/'[^']*'/).map{|m| m.gsub(/\D/, '')}
# => ["1100110011110000"]
> results[0]
# => "1100110011110000"
```

Answer (score 1):

The zeros and ones within the quoted string can be extracted using [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a regular expression, as opposed to methods that convert the string to an array of strings, modify the array and converted it back to a string. Here are three ways of doing that.

```
str ="bar9-9 '11001100 11110000 A'A\n"
```

**#1: Extract the substring of interest and then remove characters other than zero and one**

```
def extract(str)
  str[str.index("'")+1, str.rindex("'")-1].gsub(/[^01]/,'')
end

extract str
  #=> "1100110011110000"
```

**#2 Use a flag to indicate when zeroes and ones are to be kept**

```
def extract(str)
  found = false
  str.gsub(/./m) do |c|
    found = !found if c == "'" 
    (found && (c =~ /[01]/)) ? c : ''
  end
end

extract str
  #=> "1100110011110000"
```

Here the regular expression requires the `m` modifier (to enable *multiline mode*) in order to convert the newline character to an empty string. (One could alternatively write `str.chomp.gsub(/./)...`.)

Notice that this second method works when there are multiple single-quoted substrings.

```
extract "bar9-9 '11001100 11110000 A'A'10x1y'\n"
  #=> "1100110011110000101"
```

**#3 Use the [flip-flop](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/) operator (variant of #2)**

```
def extract(str)
  str.gsub(/./m) do |c|
    next '' if (c=="'") .. (c=="'")
    c =~ /[01]/ ? c : ''
  end
end

extract str
  #=> "1100110011110000"
extract "bar9-9 '11001100 11110000 A'A'10x1y'\n"
  #=> "1100110011110000101"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo.slice(/'.*?'/).scan(/\d+/).join
 #=> "1100110011110000"
```

Comment: it does not work for strings with 0 or 1 outside the quotes or for other digits inside the quotes, e.g. "01 '2345' 10".

Comment: I'd rather use `/'[^']*'/` ub `slice` to get predictable behaviour for multiple quotes, e.g. `"bar9-9 '11001100 11110000 A' 121231' A\n"`

Comment: @mrzasa Okay, I've updated the regex to be non-greedy. Also OP states _I know the string I have will always have 2 single quotes (')_ So my answer is good either way.